# How to echo out two different multi-dimensional arrays for two columns vertically in a html table

Tags: php, mysql, html

My php code throws values but mixes up both arrays data into one another. how to fix the code to sort it out! thanks in advance!

here $Array1=Array ( [0] => Array ( [0]  => Abdul Razak, Ahmed Deedat [name] => Abdul Razak, Ahmed Deedat [1] => 11 [standard] => 11 [2] => 12/08/16 [dated] => 12/08/16))
 $Array2=Array ( [0] => Array ( [0]  => lali, raj [name] => lalit, raj [1] => 12 [standard] => 12 [2] => 12/08/16 [dated] => 12/08/16))

the above arrays are just incomplete samples, rows are over 10 
I want the output like this:

```
     left wing                   |      right wing  
 array 1, key [0] values          |  array 2 [0] key values
 array1, key [1] values           |  array 2 [1] key values
 and so on till both arrays doesn't end
```

code looks like this:

```
<?php

<table id="fire">
<caption><?php echo "Achievements by the selected two are:";?> </caption>
<tr>
<th>Wing 1</th> 
<th>Wing 2</th> 
</tr> 
<tr>
<?php
if(isset($raws1)) {

foreach($raws1 as $raw1){  ?>
<tr>
<?php
if($raw1==null){
echo "<td>---</td>";
} else {
echo "<td>". $raw1['name'] . ", " . $raw1['standard'] .", on ".$raw1['dated']." ,  ".$raw1['achieved'].", at ".$raw1['at']. ", ".$raw1['on'].", (". $raw1['position'] ."</td>";
} 

if(isset($raws2)) {

foreach($raws2 as $raw2){  ?>
 <tr>
<?php
if($raw2==null){
echo "<td>---</td>";
} else {
echo "<td>". $raw2['name'] . ", " . $raw2['standard'] .", on     ".$raw2['dated']." ,  ".$raw2['achieved'].", at ".$raw2['at']. ", ".$raw2['on'].", (". $raw2['position'] ."</td></tr>";
} }}}}?>

</table>
?>
```

Comment: It was mixing both column because you had a foreach in an other foreach, Look at the bottom of your code you have 2 `}` that should'nt be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputting the beginning part of your table with headers looks like it's already fine.

```
<table id="fire">
    <caption><?php echo "Achievements by the selected two are:";?> </caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Wing 1</th> 
        <th>Wing 2</th> 
    </tr>
    <?php
```

Here's one way to do the PHP part. Put both of your arrays into one array. This will help to prevent repeated code later because you can `foreach` over the outer array to do the same things to both inner arrays.

```
$both = [$raw1, $raw2];
```

Get the maximum count of the two arrays.

```
$count = max(array_map('count', $both));
```

Then you can use a `for` loop to loop up to that maximum count.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';

    // This foreach loop will loop over the two arrays ($raw1 and $raw2)
    foreach ($both as $array) {

        // check the $i element of both the arrays and output its value if it's set
        if (empty($array[$i])) {
            echo "<td>---</td>";
        } else {
            $x = $array[$i];
            echo "<td>$x[name], $x[standard], etc. ...";
        }      
    }
    echo '</tr>';
} ?>
</table>
```

Comment: great job if it works. I am a self learner by e-books, google , ppl(geek) like u. don't have even elementry knowledge of coding langs but this answer is  giving me a good sense. it's 1am I'll try it tommorow . anyways thanks !

Comment: sorry! it's working but not the way intended. I mean it's echoing out raw1 and raw3 arrays values to the same (left) side columns as a single array but only array raw1 values are expcted for this column. there has to be a end of </td>and another <td>should echo out raw3 array values;

Comment: you're almost there to sort this out but not yet. If you could please give me any hint what else is required as the looping $i proceeds it  echos both $i at the same time because of its nature so it echo value in single column but requirement is that one [$i=0] goes to first <td> and second[$i=0] to second <td>then new raw with [$i] preceding for both columns . please help mate!

Comment: Sorry Boss! Your answer works perfectly. There was some references mistake in names that disabled me to think any more. Fixed that and glad that it's functioning perfectly. thanks a ton. and again sorry for marking your answer right so late.

Comment: @Unknown I'm glad you got it working. Sorry I couldn't respond to your comments at the time.

Comment: @ Don't Panic: you needn't to be sorry mate! you helped me in the perfect  way . I'm glad that great helpful ppl like you are there to help amateurs like me. can you tell me how to compare both arrays values at key names . I mean both the arrays you combined and created one out of them what if each of those two has two columns with integer values for both arrays I wanna find the greater one. any possibility? or just tell me how to access the combined array for individual array keys from outside of the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

I only created two new table inside, It simplified stuff alot.

It is still posible to do it in only one table. But I don't think its a requirement in your case.

Try that.

```
<table id="fire">
<caption><?php echo "Achievements by the selected two are:";?> </caption>
<tr>
    <th>Students 1</th>
    <th>student 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <?php
    if(isset($raws1)) {
        ?><table><?php

    foreach($raws1 as $raw1)
    {  ?>
    <tr>
    <?php
    if($raw1==null){
        echo "<td>---</td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td>". $raw1['name'] . ", " . $raw1['standard'] .", on ".$raw1['dated']." ,  ".$raw1['achieved'].", at ".$raw1['at']. ", ".$raw1['on'].", (". $raw1['position'] ."</td>";
    }
    ?></tr><?php
    }
    ?></table><?php
    }
    ?></td><td><?php
    if(isset($raws2)) {
        ?>
        <table>
        <?php
    foreach($raws2 as $raw2){
            ?>
        <tr>    
            <?php
    if($raw2==null){
        echo "<td>---</td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td>". $raw2['name'] . ", " . $raw2['standard'] .", on     ".$raw2['dated']." ,  ".$raw2['achieved'].", at ".$raw2['at']. ", ".$raw2['on'].", (". $raw2['position'] ."</td></tr>";
    }
        ?></tr><?php
        }
    ?></table><?php
    }?>
    </td>
    </table>
```

Comment: well!, that's the least alternative i've already prepared and working. but keeping both up against is because it's kinda head-to-head comparisiion. anyways! thanks 4 d effort.

Comment: @Unknown That answer wasn't what your were looking for ?

Comment: No! It has to be a single table dear. sorry! don't wanna annoy mate! but m stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

if your keys are the same just do a foreach loop on all keys to get data that you need.

```
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value)
{
echo "<td>{$array1[$key]}</td><td>{$array2[$key]}</td>"

}
```

Comment: but the array lenghts may differ, would it be a matter?